# Does Rust allow lib/mod.rs in place of lib.rs?

Tags: rust

Considering I have `lib.rs` and `main.rs`:
is it possible to create a `lib/` folder, to hold and separate the subfolders from `src/`,
and use `lib/` + `lib.rs` or `lib/mod.rs` to reference the submodules?

Comment: Is your question whether a binary can contain a separate library?

Comment: Not exactly, but I have that. It works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Library main file can be placed anywhere and have an arbitrary name, there's a cargo config section for that:

```
[lib]
path = "src/lib/mod.rs" # by default it is src/lib.rs
```

However, I would suggest to look at [workspaces](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch14-03-cargo-workspaces.html), it might be a better fit for you.